# Adding a child attribute to the parent element in xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have multiple elements that contain an uniqueId(generated and stored in a variable).
I have recursively added the element(object class=Bundle with unique id ) with the xsl as  follows

```
<xsl:template match="visualChildren">
    <object class="Set" >
        <installChildren>
        <xsl:call-template name="Bundle">
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="limit" select="4" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        </installChildren>
    </object>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Bundle">
     <xsl:param name="i"/>
     <xsl:param name="limit"/>

    <xsl:variable name="BundleObjId">
         <xsl:value-of select="php:function('GenerateObjId')"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $limit">
        <object class="Bundle" objectID="{$BundleObjId}">
             <property></property>
         </object>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:call-template name="Bundle">
        <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i+1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="limit" select="$limit" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

This produces the following result

```
<visualChildren>
    <object class="Set" >
        <installChildren>
            <object class="Bundle" objectID="33110emc908m">
                <property></property>
            </object>
            <object class="Bundle" objectID="43110emc9667m">
                <property></property>
            </object>
        </installChildren>
    </object>
</visualChildren>
```

Now I need to populate the BundleObjId as the parent's sibling so that it gets referenced.

Required output is:

```
<visualChildren>
    <object class="Set" >
        <installChildren>
            <object class="Bundle" objectID="33110emc908m">
                <property></property>
            </object>
            <object class="Bundle" objectID="43110emc9667m">
                 <property></property>
            </object>
        </installChildren>
    </object>
    <object RefId=33110emc908m /> 
    <object RefId=43110emc9667m /> 
 </visualChildren>
```

Please help me achieve this with xslt 1.0 by adding to the existing xsl.

Comment: OK, but what is the input XML?

Comment: I need to generate a new "Set" of elements in this case.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the input XML too? Thank you.

Comment: The XML is generated in this case. Its not edited.

Comment: The XSLT you gave us cannot generate any output, as it contains an infinite loop.

Comment: It is, because the recursive call is outside the if branch.  The condition only applies to whether an element is created or not, not to the recursion itself. *(I was responding to your comment saying that it was not infinite because there was an if, but you seem to have removed your comment)*

Comment: @Yuva Well to perform an XSL transformation, you need an input XML, and apply it a stylesheet.

Comment: @FlorentGeorges: The $limit param is initially passed with a value 4 and is passed in the xsl:call-template. It doesn't result in infinite loop.

Comment: @potame: The input contains an entirely different set of elements under <visualChildren> which i need to remove and populate with my own xml tags. There is no copy action involved in my case.

Comment: See my comment above: the recursive call is outside the xsl:if, so once you call this template, it will ALWAYS call itself recursively, will never stop.

Comment: Sir, please see that the limit parameter is passed and is evaluated against i in if statement which means that the code runs only for "limit" no. of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to provide an answer without seeing the input. I believe you need to do something like the following:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="visualChildren">
    <xsl:variable name="bundles">
        <xsl:call-template name="create-bundles">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="4" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <visualChildren>
        <object class="Set" >
            <installChildren>
                <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($bundles)/object">
                    <object class="Bundle" objectID="{@RefId}">
                        <property/>
                    </object>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </installChildren>
        </object>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$bundles"/>
    </visualChildren>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="create-bundles">
    <xsl:param name="n"/>
    <xsl:if test="$n > 0">
        <object RefId="{php:function('GenerateObjId')}"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="create-bundles">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n - 1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given an artificial input of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<visualChildren/>
```

the result will be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<visualChildren>
  <object class="Set">
    <installChildren>
      <object class="Bundle" objectID="123456">
        <property/>
      </object>
      <object class="Bundle" objectID="987654">
        <property/>
      </object>
      <object class="Bundle" objectID="456321">
        <property/>
      </object>
      <object class="Bundle" objectID="789456">
        <property/>
      </object>
    </installChildren>
  </object>
  <object RefId="123456"/>
  <object RefId="987654"/>
  <object RefId="456321"/>
  <object RefId="789456"/>
</visualChildren>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you iterate from 1 to N, instead of iterating over a nodeset.  And within that iteration, you call a function with a return value that does not depend on the context (apparently, it is generating a random string).  So you do not have any chance to repeat the same ID in 2 different iterations.  And in XSLT 1.0, you cannot generate an intermediary list of IDs, then iterate over that list.  I see 3 solutions:

- if `php:function('GenerateObjId')` can be replaced by `generate-id()`, then iterate over nodes instead, and use the latter (it will generate the same ID for 2 identical nodes)
- if your processor supports `exsl:node-set()` (most do, documentation [here](http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/)), generate the list of IDs you need, as a simple XML elements list with a single one parent element, store it in a variable, then use `exsl:node-set()` to iterate over (twice)
- if you can, switch to XSLT 2.0 (where you can apply the previous solution, without the need for `exsl:node-set()` as, in XSLT 2.0, you can use what are result trees in XSLT 1.0 as input to XPath expressions)

Last "solution" (in case none of the above is possible):

- apply a second transform to the result of you first transform, based on the Modified Identity Transform pattern:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

```
   <xsl:template match="node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="object[@class = 'Set']">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      <xsl:for-each select="installChildren/object">
         <object RefId="{ @objectID }"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```

Comment: In this case, xslt is integrated with a php engine and the system has an inbuilt mechanism to generate the Unique id. My issue was to copy the generated unique id to the parent as a reference to point the child nodes.

Comment: And you cannot post-process (e.g. copy something from) a result tree in XSLT 1.0.  Hence the suggestion to move to XSLT 2.0 (e.g. using Saxon in PHP), or use an extension to be able to do so in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: "*And in XSLT 1.0, you cannot generate an intermediary list of IDs, then iterate over that list.*" You are quite wrong about that.

Comment: I mean you cannot use a result tree in XPath.  How would you do it?

Comment: Which is the 2d option I describe above.  It needs an extension because it is not possible in XSLT 1.0, you need EXSLT's `node-set()` for that.  This function was the starting point for the whole EXSLT project by the way, because it was providing the most missed feature in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Using EXSLT's node-set() function is (by far) the most convenient way to do that, but it's not the only one. You just need to make sure that the "intermediary list of IDs" is created as a node-set to begin with, and maintained as such.

Comment: And it is not possible to create nodesets in XSLT 1.0 and operate on them.  Of course, your environment can create that XML for you and provide it as input to your stylesheet, but still, it is not possible in XSLT 1.0.